# Dynamics CRM current date placeholder in workflows

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm

I've workflow attached to an entity which has expiration date and time, so what is the appropriate placeholder which indicates the current time some sort of `{{CURRENT_TIME}}` ).

Sultan

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question is a little vague but if you are talking about Dynamics CRM workflows via the editor, the time that the workflow is running at would be the execution time.

To get this, do the following steps -

- Within a workflow on a create or update step, click in a date/time field on the form.
- In the form assistant on the right side, let the *Look for* dropdown to "Process"
- Set the sub-dropdown to "Execution Time"
- Click Add
- Click OK

This will put the current time the workflow is executing into the form field.  Screenshot below -

[image: CRM Workflow]