# Dynamic marketing list excluding static list? possible in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have started learning CRM 2011 some couple of weeks ago as my job requires me to get in to it. I am from SharePoint and SQL background. Know other of ASP.NET or oData etc...

My question is, I have dynamic marketing list and our head od marketing want to use that but wants to exclude a static list of customers. We have some bad data and they are bouncing back in email marketing.

Is there any way to create a dynamic marketing list and then exclude a static marketing list from it? Any help will be gratful (links would be awsome!)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, I've played for a while, I was able to create a dynamic marketing list which included the results of a static list, but I couldn't get it to exclude a static list.

My suggestion would be to find a commonality (or create one, e.g. a new field or possibly using the marketing preferences) between those contacts and add that filter into your dynamic list.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am hitting dead end with this too. I was think I will have to find some kind of work around that you suggested. Wondering if any thing can be done with workflow.

Comment: Agree, James. Since I come from the background of SharePoint, anwser to all my questions is 'Workflow' ;) I have just started learning CRM for my new job and found out that can't even get todays date on workflow (using built-in layout)... there are so many questions and so little time!

Comment: You can get todays date by using the execution time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151949/dynamics-crm-current-date-placeholder-in-workflows

Comment: Many many many thanks James, that is the answer I was looking for. Ace stuff. :D

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but I thought let me add the solution I now use for this issue.

Out of box this is not possible as mentioned by others. This is what I did to fix it:
1. Add temp flag in crm
2. Create a basic Windows form application where you search for a static market list that you would like to exclude (drop down menu was too big)
3. once selected the correct static marketing list, hit the button that will set the temp flag value of all contacts in this marketing list to '1'.
4. When creating dynamic list, add extra criteria, where temp flag is != 1.

Once the campaign is sent, reset temp flag to 0.